# how to setState the data from localstorage into an array of object in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, todomvc

this is my setState in APP.js

```
this.state = {
       todos:[
        {id:0, content:'Welcome Sir!',isCompleted:true},

       ]
    }
  }
```

here I fetched the data from local srorage

```
    this.documentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));


}
```

I fetched the data from localstorage but confused how to store it into State
the data fetch in format 
`{content: "dd",id: 0.10599785413372431,isCompleted: true}`
note that this is a todo app so every time we create a task means we create an object

Comment: so the localStorage data was a list of todos or just ONE object of todo ??

Comment: when you storing in local you need first make your data `JSON.stringify` after that you will get a good result.
`localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(todos))`

Comment: @DucHong one object todo

Comment: @SanatGupta yes the data is already stored into local storage using the method you define

Comment: @DeepakBhamla then you just need setState right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your localStorage was just one object of To-do. I think you can try this to set new data into your array of objects:

```
this.setState( prevState => ({
  todos: [
    ...prevState.todos,
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'))
  ]
}))
```

Notice that this assumes you're writing component as Class.

Comment: Yes it work but if we want list of objects  I means how to store all the todos in local storage and then fetch all them how it is possible

Comment: the storing idea is the same, first you need to have a complete list of Todos, usually this is an array, then calling `JSON.stringify` this to store into your localStorage. If you want to retrieve this data,  just `JSON.parse` like you did, but now it's an array of Todos, not just one single object.

Comment: `localStorage` just plays as a cache layer here, you can store whatever you want, since the accepted format is just STRING. No wonder you need to `stringify` the data first before storing, and `parse` before actually using it

Comment: how to do it and where put it

Comment: this is out of the context we're discussing, are you developing this or just maintaining from another developer ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on information available, below code will work -

```
onNewTaskClickHandler = () => {
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    todos: [].concat(prevState.todos).concat(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')))
}));
}
```